# Django CreateView Not Working as expected

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have the following **CreateView**

```
class CreateEmailTemplateView(CreateView):

   template_name = 'frontend/emailtemplates/create.html'
   model = Templates
   fields = '__all__'

   def form_valid(self, form):
      form.instance.user = self.request.user
      return super(CreateEmailTemplateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

And the **Templates** model looks like this

```
class Templates(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    template = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**But when I submit the form it doesn't persist it in the database nor I see any error messages,** it simply redirects to the same page, The form method is `POST`

What am I missing? How can I show some error/success message after the form submission ?

Comment: I think the problem here is that your form basically requires a `user`, (since `fields='__all__`), so that means the form is probably never valid.

Comment: Ahh.... Ok, Now the form_valid method is getting called, How can I show a message after the save in this case?

Comment: How canI show validation errors in case of createview?

Answer (score 1):

`form_valid` is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
Could you please check if your data is valid?
You can also add logging into your `form_valid` method to make sure you reach it:

```
import logging


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class CreateEmailTemplateView(CreateView):

    template_name = 'frontend/emailtemplates/create.html'
    model = Templates
    fields = '__all__'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        logger.info('form_valid called')
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(CreateEmailTemplateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: I have added a breakpoint in form_valid method, but its not getting called and the log is also not coming, How do I make sure the validity of the form data from create view?

Comment: Probably your form is not valid. Try to change view type and submit the same form data, so you can debug your data right after dispatch.

Comment: How can I validate the form in case of the createView?

Comment: @ShobiPP you could use ModelForm.